# Better version of "the best thing I ever did in 2018 is I came to USA"

Tags: grammar

What can I do to the following sentence, which one I should choose, and can I delete the *I* in the sentence?

> the best thing I ever did/done in 2018 was/is (I) came to USA

Answer (score 6):

The **Simple Past**, as used below, is idiomatic and common among American and British English speakers

> 1. *Coming to **the** USA **was** the best thing I ever **did***

The definite article "the" is always required whenever we speak about the *United States of* America even when it is abbreviated (the USA *also* the US). By saying "I *ever* did" the speaker is referring to their entire lifetime.

The **Present Perfect** could also be used but the auxiliary *have* is necessary to construct the phrase correctly.

> 2. *The best thing I **have** ever **done** was **come** to the USA*

After expressions such as "have ever done" and "all I did" the verb that follows can be in the bare infinitive (without "to") or to-infinitive.

> 3. *All I did was **come** to the USA* (completely different meaning)
> 4. *The best thing I ever did was **to come** to the USA*

If nominating a year is essential then eliminate "ever" and instead say

> 5. *The best thing I did **in 2018** was **to come** to the USA*
> 6. ***Coming*** to the US was the best thing I did **in 2018**

Answer (score 4):

Except for the unidiomatic combination of **ever ... in 2018**  your sentence is grammatical and idiomatic; it is in a conversational, not a formal, register.

Perhaps you meant to say the following?

> The best thing I ever did is, I came to the USA in 2018.

**ever** means "throughout all time" or "in my entire life", so it can't be coupled with a phrase that runs counter to that meaning.

Comment: Nice answer. In addition, I think the following are common, grammatical, idiomatic, and close to the OP's referent utterance: *The best thing I ever did was [to] come to the USA in 2018; Coming to the USA in 2018 was the best thing I ever did.* *Ever* is almost always frustrating for ELs, because, at least for one thing, it has two major meanings: at any time, and at all times. One natural inclination is to use it like Q: *Did you ever visit Japan?* A: *Yes, I ever visited Japan.* (Substitute for "once".)

Answer (score 4):

Logically, 'ever' and 'in 2018' don't go together.
So you should pick only one of them.
And I think it's redundant to repeat "I" as in "I came..." because you already said "I did" at the outset.

So you can choose any one of these:

> The best thing I did in 2008 was come to the U.S.
>
> The best thing I ever did was come to the U.S. (in 2018.)
>
> The best thing I've ever done is come to the U.S. (in 2018.)

Comment: It should be `to come to`, not just `come to`.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström No, the default form is _come to_.

Answer (score 0):

Saying something like "I ever did" and then narrowing it down to a year doesn't make much sense. Instead, you could say something like, "The best thing I did in 2018 was I came to the USA"

Answer (score 0):

What is the "thing" that you did? The "thing" is "coming to USA" not "I came to..."